# Number of ways in which $2010$ can be formed using $2,5,10$.

Tags: combinatorics, dynamic-programming

We can form $10$ using $2,5,10$ in $3$ ways. In how many ways can we form $2010(201*10)$. My teacher mentioned. $202*203/2$ I cannot figure out how. 
I also saw a DP method for finding number of ways in which a sum can be obtained. If there is a direct formula for calculating this after finding it to some factor of a number, Why do we have a polynomial time algorithm?

Comment: what is a dp method?

Comment: Dynamic programming method. It is way we memorize the number of coins required for making 1,2,3,.... and arrive at 2010

Comment: Factoring is not generally doable in polynomial time. (However, your DP algorithm is only polynomial in terms of the input itself—with regard to the size of the input, it is exponential.)

Comment: It seems we do not need to find all factors. Just one will enough? I guess something is wrong with my assumption That by finding for a factor we could find for the whole sum. This might work in this case. But not sure in all cases. To check if it works I need to first understand how he came up with that formula.

Answer (score 2):

This might not be the smartest way to solve this. You want to solve $2x+5y+10z=2010$ for $x,y,z$ nonnegative integers.

We see $y$ must be even say $=2y'$ (why?), so we have $2x+10y'+10z=2010$, that is $x+5y'+5z=1005$. We must have $5\mid x'$ so we want to solve $x'+y'+z=201$. This is the coefficient of $x^{201}$ in $(1+x+x^2+\cdots)(1+x+x^2+\cdots)(1+x+x^2+\cdots)$ (why?)

Since $$\frac{1}{(1-x)^3}=\sum_{k\geqslant 0}\binom{2+k}{k}x^k=\sum_{k\geqslant 0}\frac{(2+k)(k+1)}{2}x^k$$

this gives $\dfrac{203\cdot 202}{2}$ solutions.

Answer (score 2):

We have to solve the equation $$2x+5y+10z=2010\tag{1}$$
in nonnegative integers. From $(1)$ we immediately deduce that $x$ has to divisible by $5$, and $y$ has to be divisible by $2$. Writing $x=5u$, $y=2v$ we obtain the new equation
$$u+v+z=201\ ,\tag{2}$$
which has
$$N:={201+2\choose 2}=20\,503$$
solutions in nonnegative integers. (This is a "stars and bars" problem: Any solution $(u,v,z)$ of $(2)$ can be encoded as a binary sequence consisting of $u$ stars, a bar, $v$ stars, a bar, and $z$ stars, containing $201$ stars in all. There are ${203\choose 2}$ such sequences.) The number $N$ is also the solution to the original problem.

Comment: Sir, How is (203 C 2) obtained?

Answer (score 1):

a number $10n$ can be formed using $10$ and $5$ only in $n+1$ ways (there can be any number from $0$ to $n$ $10$-coins)

The previous statement implies the number of $2$-coins must be a multiple of $5$

since $2010=201\cdot2\cdot5$ the number of $2$-coins can be any number between $0$ and $201$ and using the previous paragraph this means that when there are exactly $5k$ coins of value $2$ there are $\frac{210-10k}{10}+1$ ways to pay the remaining cash using $2$ and $5$ coins.Using this we see there are $202+201+\dots+2+1$ ways to make up $2010$ using $2,5$ and$10$-coins. Using Gaussian summation we find this is equal to $\frac{202\cdot203}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

Since we have $$2x+5y+10z=2010\Rightarrow 2x=5(402-y-2z),$$ $x$ has to be represented as $x=5k$. Hence we have
$$2\cdot 5k+5y+10z=2010\Rightarrow 2k+y+2z=402\Rightarrow y=2(201-k-z).$$
Since $y$ has to be even, letting $y=2m$, we have
$$2k+2m+2z=402\Rightarrow k+m+z=201\Rightarrow m+z=201-k.$$
Since for each $0\le k\le 201$ such that $m+z=201-k$, there are $201-k+1$ pairs for $(m,z)$.

Hence, the answer is
$$\sum_{k=0}^{201}(201-k+1)=202+\sum_{k=1}^{201}k=202+\frac{201\cdot 202}{2}=\frac{202\cdot 203}{2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
As [${\tt @Christian Blatter}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/893099/85343) and [${\tt @mathlove}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/893088/85343)  have already shown in their straightforward answers, it's sufficient to look for combinations of $\ds{\braces{a,b,c}}$ such that
$\ds{a + b + c = 201}$. Those are given by:

> \begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large \sum_{a=0}^{\infty}\sum_{b=0}^{\infty}\sum_{c=0}^{\infty}
> \delta_{a\ +\ b\ +\ c\ ,\ 201}}
> =\sum_{a=0}^{\infty}\sum_{b=0}^{\infty}\sum_{c=0}^{\infty}
> \oint_{0\ <\ \verts{z}\ <\ 1}\
> {1 \over z^{-a - b - c + 202}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[3mm]&=\oint_{0\ <\ \verts{z}\ <\ 1}\ {1 \over z^{202}}
> \sum_{a=0}^{\infty}z^{a}\sum_{b=0}^{\infty}z^{b}
> \sum_{c=0}^{\infty}z^{c}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> =\oint_{0\ <\ \verts{z}\ <\ 1}\
> {1 \over z^{202}}\,{1 \over \pars{1 - z}^{3}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[5mm]&=\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{k}{-3 \choose k}\
> \overbrace{\oint_{0\ <\ \verts{z}\ <\ 1}\
> {1 \over z^{202 - k}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}}
> ^{\color{#c00000}{\ds{=\ \delta_{k\,,\,201}}}}
> =\pars{-1}^{201}{-3 \choose 201}
> \\[5mm]&=-\braces{\pars{-1}^{201}{-\bracks{-3} + 201 - 1 \choose 201}}
> ={203 \choose 201} = {203! \over 201!\ 2!} = {203\times 202 \over 2}
> =203\times 101
> \\[3mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large 20503}
> \end{align}